# Display popup using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to display the popup message when the page loads. I am getting the popup when the page loads. But the problem is the close `button` bar in pop up window. The button looks bigger than the bar. So I want the button fit inside the bar. How to change the size of the bar?

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {  
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      width : 700,
      height : 400,
      modal: true   
    });   
  });
  </script>
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
 

</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title=" ">
  <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="350" src="popUp.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Actual and Expected Screen shots]

Comment: It's working as expected.

Comment: So what is that hard that you had to post here?! What have you tried? In your above code I don't see anything to suggest me that you tried to do something about this.

Comment: could you specify clearly? the width or height of the close button?

Comment: The title and question is a bit misleading, but the question text is explaining what he wants. If I understand correctly he wants to set the title bar height to bigger, so the button won't be out of the bar. In that case see my answer.

Comment: @Narendrakumar M - Could you please elaborate your question correctly?

Comment: I have update myanswer

Comment: @WisdmLabs i need to fix the "X" within the bar.

Comment: Can I able to change the color of bar

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with css. Example:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    height: 15px;
}
```

The same with updating color:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar {
    height: 15px;
    background: #EBB7B7;
}
```

See JsFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/p1022vse/).
With color change: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/p1022vse/1/)

Comment: Thank you. It help me alot.. Can I able to change the color of the bar.

Comment: Sure, you can add to it `background: red` or hexa code of color like: `background: #EBB7B7`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>


</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title=" ">
  <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="670" height="350" src="popUp.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>
    .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    height: 15px;
}
    </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {        
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
         width : 700,
         height : 400,
         modal: true   
    });   
  });
  </script>
```

Demo:http://js.do/code/73753